# What is the difference between nested virtual directories and nested folders in IIS?

Tags: c#, iis

We have a site configured in `IIS` with one virtual directory, call it `myapp`. We are now in the process of creating sub-directories for the testing (call it `tst`), internal acceptance (call it `iat`) and user acceptance (call it `uat`) paths, each with their own version(s) as an application.

The below paths illustrate what we are attempting: 
`https://mysite.domain.com/myapp/tst/v1/*` or `https://mysite.domain.com/myapp/uat/v5/*`

My question is whether there is a difference between creating the `tst` or `uat` sub-directories as virtual directories, or can they be created as folder within the `myapp` application. We have gone for the normal folder route, but not sure if that is the correct/best practice way?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/planning-your-iis-architecture/understanding-sites-applications-and-virtual-directories-on-iis If sites/applications are excluded, virtual directories and physical directories are almost equivalent (except the virtual ones are virtual).

Answer (score 0):

A virtual directory can be used for two main purposes:
It can be included in an application to either modify the URL of the application, for example:

Say the application is stored in `wwwroot/mysite/myapp/deployment/uat/v1`, you can use virtual directories to change the URL: `https://mysite.domain.com/myapp/uat/v1/` by pointing the virtual directory to `wwwroot/mysite/myapp/deployment/`
This can also be used to hide the actual structure of your site.

A virtual path can also be used to reference resources stored in another physical location.
If you reference images in `wwwroot/mysite/myapp/deployment/imgs` you can create a virtual directory called imgs in iis under ther deployments folder and let that virtual directory point to the location of the resources you need.

But to answer your question, it shouldn't change the way your application behaves if it is actual directories or virtual directories.
Here is a link to the Microsoft docs explaining the purpose of virtual directories: [Virtual Directories](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.applicationhost/sites/site/application/virtualdirectory)